# NodeJS Express enumerate files in a folder

Tags: node.js, express

Sorry, I'm new with NodeJS Express. I want to get all files from a folder. I tried the following but don't work, test is always empty string:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var test = '';

    const testFolder = './public/images';

    fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
      test = files[0];
    })

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', file: test });
});
```

Basically, I want to get all filenames from public images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is `res.render()` will be executed before `test` is assigned to `files[0]`, because the `fs.readdir` is asynchronous process. Before your callback is called `res.render` is excuted. And also, if you are trying to get all files from the folder you should pass `files` array. Please take a look at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) for more info. You might wanna try the below code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var test = '';

    const testFolder = './public/images';

    fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
       // test = files[0]; this will assign test to the first element of the array of file
       test = files;
       res.render('index', { title: 'Express', file: test });
    })


});
```

Comment: still on the learning curve on Node. Thank you @Tolsee for your help.